# How to take a certain data index of Future<List> item

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart, flutter-http

I Have a problem to take the newest data index

```
class User {
  final String idUser,
  name,
  phone;

  User(
    {this.idUser,
    this.name,
    this.phone});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
    idUser: json['_id'],
    name: json['name'],
    phone: json['phone']);
  }
}

List<User> userFromJson(jsonData) {
  List<User> result =
    List<User>.from(jsonData.map((item) => User.fromJson(item)));

  return result;
}

// index
Future<List<User>> fetchUser() async {
  String route = AppConfig.API_ENDPOINT + "userdata";
  final response = await http.get(route);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResp = json.decode(response.body);

    return userFromJson(jsonResp);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed load $route, status : ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

and the calling method just like this

```
user = fetchUser();
```

the "response.body" valued like this

> [{"_id":"4136425eb8d9320f4822c554","name":"John","phone":"90643755394"},{"_id":"62766b2eb45s3w0g4662ftd3","name":"Anna","timestamp":"90345765791"}]

I expect it was how to take the first index to get the newest data, but I don't know ho the code will be. Also if there are another soltion to get that newest data, please let me know, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index to get the specific value from a list

```
userFromJson(jsonResp[0]); /// For first record
```

Comment: on the List<User> userFromJson(jsondata) it return error _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => User' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Comment: Okay keep everything as yours and return result[0]

Comment: it's turn out invalid syntax   A value of type 'User' can't be returned from the function 'userFromJson' because it has a return type of 'List<User>'.

Comment: Is the total list returning from above code

Comment: I mean if I modify return result into return result[0] the word "result[0]" underlined red, so it could not be run

Comment: Without doing any changes will your code return the list???

Comment: yes it return a list

Comment: Okay then get user[0]

Comment: it works on my program, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use array index number to get the first object in array.

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResp = json.decode(response.body);

    return List<User>.from(jsonResp.map((user) => User.fromJson(user)));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed load $route, status : ${response.statusCode}');
  }
```

If you want to get one user only

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResp = json.decode(response.body);

    return User.fromJson(jsonResp[0]);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed load $route, status : ${response.statusCode}');
  }
```

Other method is by modifying the Query using `LIMIT 1`

Comment: on the List<User> userFromJson(jsondata) it return error _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => User' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Comment: can you post your json result? So we have a clear image about how to handle the data

Comment: the response.body valued: [{"_id":"4136425eb8d9320f4822c554","name":"John","phone":"90643755394"},{"_id":"62766b2eb45s3w0g4662ftd3","name":"Anna","timestamp":"90345765791"}]

Comment: Okay I edit my answer, please check it.

Comment: using User.fromJson(jsonResp[0]); returning error on me A value of type 'User' can't be returned from the function 'fetchUser' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<User>>'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type

Comment: how about the method of "Other method is by modifying the Query using LIMIT 1"?

Comment: @Alfan for that error, change `Future<List<User>>` to `Future<User>`. The other method is change your query, so something like this `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1`.

Comment: I don't know it represent succesful or not, when I print the variable into string, it valued Instance of 'User'

Comment: Yup, because you access the user directly, try user.name

Answer (score 0):

Because its Future You have to use the await keyword to get the completed result so modify your code by adding await

```
users = await fetchUser();
```

now you can access the user list

```
var firstUser = users.first;
var firstUser = users[0];
```

For more await and  async you can read this [Asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

Comment: is "users.first" mean the attribute named "first" in a class named "user" of object name "users"?

Comment: no its attribute of the List  users[0] and users.first give the  same result

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-core/List/first.html

Comment: if I print the firstUser, it valued Instance of 'User'

Comment: Your  data  its a List<User> and firstUser its the first element from that list so you can access the `firstUser.idUser` and `firstUser.name`  and `firstUser.phone`